# Populate an array with random numbers in the range of 0-4 with an increment of 0.5

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, random, increment

So I have initialised an array to size 10 and trying to populate it with random numbers in the range 0.5-4 at an increment of 0.5 using a for loop. This was my initial attempt:

```
double increment = 0.5;
double[] numbers = new double[10];
Random nextVal = new Random();
double value = 0;

for (int i = 0;i < numbers.length;i++){
    value = 0.5 + nextVal.nextInt(5);
    while (value == 4.5){
        value = value - increment;
    }
    numbers[i] = value;
}
```

However, this only adds 0.5 to the random integer values in the range instead of incrementing by 0.5.

Maybe the for-loop isn't the right approach because of the differences in `int` and `double` variables...not totally sure. Any hints or help would be great! Thanks

Comment: Do you want only the first integer to be (pseudo)random and the rest should be in 0.5 increments?

Comment: Show an example of a suitable output.  _"random numbers in the range 0.5-4 at an increment of 0.5"_ does not make sense.

Comment: Hint: learn a bit about floating point numbers. Using == to compare them indicates already that you have some big holes in your theoretical knowledge.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz  -- The first number doesn't necessarily need to be an integer. The possible numbers I want to randomly pick from are 0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,....,4. So each time a random number is picked it could be either an integer(1,2,3,4) or a double(0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5). Does that make sense?

Comment: @GhostCat I'm still fairly new, I'll do some research on that cheers! The function of the while loop was only checking if the value was 4.5 and changing it to 4.

Comment: @JimGarrison Hey so once the array was filled randomly with different numbers in the range 0.5 - 4 at an increment of 0.5, I'd be looking for something like this to be printed out: [0.5 ,2.5, 0.5, 4, 3.5, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1.5] as an example. Because of the size of the array there would be duplicates, but that is fine. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @cpfleck, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments:

```
double[] numbers = new double[10];
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    numbers[i] = 0.5 + (random.nextInt(8)) * 0.5;
    System.out.println(numbers[i]);
}
```

`random.nextInt(8)` picks an integer from `[0, 8)`... which is then multiplied by `0.5`... this is how you get numbers from `[0, 4)`. Later you add `0.5`, which gives you a number from `[0.5, 4.5)`.
You can repeat this `10` times to fill your array.